# Type '{ path: string; component: () => Element; }' is not assignable to type Property 'component'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

Estoy tratando de crear rutas usando **react-router-dom en versión 6.2.1**  `npm i react-router-dom @types/react-router-dom` y me despliega el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Type '{ path: string; component: () => Element; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'.
  Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (PathRouteProps | LayoutRouteProps | IndexRouteProps)'.ts(2322)
```

***Mi código es el siguiente:***

```
import "./App.css"
import Nav from "./components/Nav"
import {BrowserRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav />

      <main className="form-signin">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route path="/" component={Home} /> // acá despliega el error.
        </BrowserRouter>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Alguna explicación de lo que está pasando?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ya no se usa `component` , ahora es `element`, intenta de esta manera

`<Route path="/" element={<Home />} />`

y debes envolverlo en `Routes`

quedando de esta manera

```
   <div className="App">
      <Nav />

      <main className="form-signin">
        <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>
           <Route path="/" element={<Home />} /> 
         </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </main>
    </div>
```